# Spyder Python: A plus B

Tags: python, spyder

```
import sys
input = sys.stdin.read()
tokens = input.split()
a = int(tokens[0])
b = int(tokens[1])
print(a + b)
```

When I run the code above in the IDE *Spyder*, give the input as `2 3` and press `ctrl-d`, it just shows `(2,3)` rather than `5`.

Comment: May I ask why you're using `sys.stdin.read()` rather than `input()` (other than because you shadowed the latter with the result of the former)?

Comment: I am a new python-er and want to use different input function to run the same case.

Comment: And the above code works fine for me. Did you make a change in the editor and then rerun the code without first saving the changes?

Comment: This is my first time using Spyder and just open the APlusB.py file and click the 'run file' botton.